# Error installing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a problem with installing Visual Studio. I can't install it, the progress bar isn't moving. I checked the Task Manager and it is in 0% CPU usage (which means that it isn't working)

Any ideas?

Comment: Let me google that for you... visual studio installation problems ... oh, first result: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee225241%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 

Also, next time before asking please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is off topic for this website.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-downloading the installer and running it with Administrative privileges. If that doesn't work, restart your computer. Make sure all other programs are closed when installing. Make sure you have Microsoft .NET installed ([you can get it here](http://www.microsoft.com/net)).

Comment: .net doesn't need to be installed as a pre condition.

Comment: Hm. I thought it did. I guess it doesn't matter, OP should have googled it before posting it off-topic here. I'm sorry you felt the need to vote down my answer.

Comment: I didn't wote you down. Just added the comment